# How can a nodejs TLS server seperate all connected clients?

Tags: node.js, express, tls1.2

If multiple clients are connecting to a server using tls.createServer(), the server can communicate with the client that connects, through

```
const server = tls.createServer(options, function(
socket.write('hello!')
});
```

How can I make the server send message to all connected clients when a new client connects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep an array or object to record all connections. It can be useful for further process whatever it may be.

Please look through the given link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982259/tls-to-multiple-clients-and-different-messages/52983057#52983057)

I hope you can find what you expected.